# Alamofire 1.2.2 in Xcode 7.2 errors

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, xcode7.2

I have Xcode IDE 7.2 on iMac

I checked out a project from svn with alamofire version is 1.2.2

Now i'm getting 34 issues all related to alamofire ios (33 issues) and alamofire osx (1 issue)

[image]

What is the problem of these errors? Any idea how can i fix them?

Thanks a lot

Comment: That image is tiny and I can't make anything out

Comment: A photo of the screen? XD At least post a **`screenshot`**. Or even better, post the actual error message.

Comment: @chedabob check the edit plz =)

Comment: @luk2302 check the edit plz =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to update Alamofire. This version is no longer compatible with version of Swift you have. I guess this version of Alamofire is compatible with Swift 1.2 (old names of protocols, # in parameter list etc.)